# Create a 2-dimensional NumPy array a1 with 10 rows and 10 columns that contains the squares of the first 100 odd numbers, starting from 1

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

```
a = np.arange(start = 1, stop = 201, step = 2)
a = np.power(a, 2)
a1 = np.reshape(a, (10, 10))
a1
```

That's my input but for some reason it's wrong. Can someone help me figure this out? I keep getting this error:

[image: error output]

Comment: What does "wrong" mean? Do you get an error? What result do you get which isn't expected?

Answer (score 1):

This code does produce the output you want. What makes you say it isn't correct?

```
>>> a1
array([[    1,     9,    25,    49,    81,   121,   169,   225,   289,
          361],
       [  441,   529,   625,   729,   841,   961,  1089,  1225,  1369,
         1521],
       [ 1681,  1849,  2025,  2209,  2401,  2601,  2809,  3025,  3249,
         3481],
       [ 3721,  3969,  4225,  4489,  4761,  5041,  5329,  5625,  5929,
         6241],
       [ 6561,  6889,  7225,  7569,  7921,  8281,  8649,  9025,  9409,
         9801],
       [10201, 10609, 11025, 11449, 11881, 12321, 12769, 13225, 13689,
        14161],
       [14641, 15129, 15625, 16129, 16641, 17161, 17689, 18225, 18769,
        19321],
       [19881, 20449, 21025, 21609, 22201, 22801, 23409, 24025, 24649,
        25281],
       [25921, 26569, 27225, 27889, 28561, 29241, 29929, 30625, 31329,
        32041],
       [32761, 33489, 34225, 34969, 35721, 36481, 37249, 38025, 38809,
        39601]])
```